# C++ pass by reference and temporary variables

Tags: c++

Is temporary variable created in program below??

```
void swapr(int & a, int & b)  // use references 
{ 
    int temp;
    temp = a;      // use a, b for values of variables 
    a = b; 
    b = temp;
} 
long a = 3, b = 5; 
swapr(a, b);
```

in the above code what difference does it make if i use const reference instead?
it is said that it creates temporary variable which is swapped instead of actual variable..

if above code cant perform swapping? what is the right code to perform swapping using same data and  also using pass by reference?

Comment: You can't assign to `const &`.  That's what `const` means.

Comment: In the above code using `const&` will give you a compilation error.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You seem to basically know what `const` means and what the difference between a call-by-value parameter and a call-by-reference parameter is. You seem to not have simply tried the effect of using both. But otherwise I really don't see what your question is. Please combine your knowledge on const and on reference to some insight on const references and then explain what exactly is still unclear to you.

Comment: when does compiler create temporary varible? is above code supposed to create temporary variable? it is showing error telling me cant convert arguments long to int&

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE you can bind compatible\convertible type to a const reference, in that case a temporary value is created, is that what you are asking? But you can't change that value inside of function. You can't bind temporary rvalue to a non-const reference, it requires a matching type

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie i'm asking that is it possible to create temporary variable if i do not use constat reference?  or is it compulsory to use constant reference in order for the program to create temporary variable?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie why is Temporary variable not created in the above program?

Comment: Just use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and stop thinking about it

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE it's an ill-formed program, you can't compile that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will perform the swapping except for the fact that your function accepts integers and you are trying to swap long variables. If your long value exceeds max integer size, it will result in an overflow. So define a separate function for long values.

A reference variable (defined as: `int& var;`)means a variable that refers to the same variable as another variable. So any change in one variable will also reflect the other variable. So your swapping will also affect the actual argument values.

There are two reasons you define a function parameters as reference variables.
One like your case where you want the actual variables to be modified.
Second is to prevent the copying overhead.
So:

```
void func(int& a, int& b);
```

Will pass your arguments as reference, so a and b will refer to the same variables.
But:

```
void func(int a, int b);
```

Will copy the values of your variables to a and b which is more time consuming.

Now,

**`const& var`**
Here the variable is not only passed as reference but also it ensures that the function can't modify the original variable.
`const` variables cannot be changed.
So if you include const in your function parameter list like this:

```
void rswap(const int& a, const int& b);
```

you will get an error because you are trying to modify a and b that is swap them.
`const` is used for protection when passing variables as reference so that they don't accidentally get modified in the function.
Usually useful when you just want to print the values or use the values without modifying them.

Comment: i m refering to c++ primer 5th edition and it says if this type of condition occures when reference variable type do not match with given argument temporary variable is created ? is temporary variable created in this program?

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will reject your code if you use const reference in your function.

By const you promise to not to modify the variable.

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE never heard of it. Even if it does you don’t have access to that to improve your performance. Please note that passing by reference in scalar types doesn’t improve performance. And you have a good reason to pass by reference here.

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE passing a const reference though prolongs the lifetime of temporary until function returns. So your function can accept a temporary while non-const will reject it. F(2) is accepted on F(const int &) and rejected by F(int &). The temporary here created in the function call and will pass through the function.